# how to customize color for C format specifier and variable in vim

Tags: c, vim

I am writing a simple C program to test my own colorscheme if it works or not. And I want to change the color of variable and format specifier(%d,%s.%f,...).

How should I do it?

I did try to configure the vim Identifier but it has no effect on the real Identifier(variable name) in my C code. Also which option should I use along with :hi for changing the color of format specifier.

[image]

Comment: Probably a better fit on the specialized [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)...?

Comment: This is not a question about programming.  No reason to be tagged either `c` or `vim`.  Voted to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to change the color of variable and format specifier

The group for format specifiers is called `cFormat`. Normally it's linked to `cSpecialChar` (which includes `\n`, `\r` and such).

You can't change variable highlight, as it's just `Normal`.

Comment: Hello my C Format Specifier is already changed due to your advice but It didn't seem to be linked to cSpecialChar. Also I can't find cSpecialChar with :help.

Comment: @Trunganhnguyễnthành This is done in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim`. The highlight groups from second level syntax subplugins are not documented in Vim's help.